# How to cast Int to BigInt in Scala

Tags: scala, casting, int, bigint

I have Int

```
val y = 10
```

I want to cast to BigInt

```
y.toBigInt
```

it show error

```
<console>:26: error: value toBigInt is not a member of Int
       y.toBigInt
```

How can I cast Int to BigInt ?

Comment: why not `val d :BigInt = 10 `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is example:

```
val i: Int = 1
val bigInt = BigInt(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

All the obvious methods work. You can assign an `Int` to a `BigInt`, you can pass an `Int` to a function that takes `BigInt`, and you can just use `BigInt(y)`.